# Issue in automating Gmail Sign up using Watir

Tags: ruby, automated-tests, watir-webdriver

I am automating gmail sign up using Watir,I am facing error while setting month dropdown box.I am not able to pick exact month.I am testing with Firefox on Windows7.Please find my source code below and please help me out

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
  require "watir-webdriver/wait"
  ie=Watir::Browser.new :firefox
  ie.goto "gmail.com"
  ie.text_field(:id,"FirstName").set("Info")  
  ie.text_field(:id,"LastName").set("Gain")  
  ie.text_field(:id,"GmailAddress").set("infoblr123")   
  ie.text_field(:id,"Passwd").set("infoblr123$")   
  ie.text_field(:id,"PasswdAgain").set("infoblr123$")   
  ie.element(:css, "#BirthMonth > div").click
  ie.element(:text, "May").click
  ie.text_field(:id, "BirthDay").set "11"
  ie.text_field(:id, "BirthYear").set "1992
```

Comment: What is your use case here?  Why do you want to automate signing up for gmail?  If your goal is to have an destination for emails, why not use gmail's [API](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/)?

Answer (score 0):

Hi The above code chooses the month fine, There is no problem here. But you have missed a line 'ie.link(:text,'Create account').click' here.

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require "watir-webdriver/wait"
ie=Watir::Browser.new :chrome
ie.goto "gmail.com"
ie.link(:text,'Create account').click # you have missed out this line
ie.text_field(:id,"FirstName").set("Info")
ie.text_field(:id,"LastName").set("Gain")
ie.text_field(:id,"GmailAddress").set("infoblr123")
ie.text_field(:id,"Passwd").set("infoblr123$")
ie.text_field(:id,"PasswdAgain").set("infoblr123$")
ie.element(:css, "#BirthMonth > div").click
ie.element(:text, "May").click
ie.text_field(:id, "BirthDay").set "11"
ie.text_field(:id, "BirthYear").set "1992"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,But,though,its clicking on month dropdown,its not selecting the specified month.Could you please help me out.

Comment: No, it's selecting properly for me. It runs fine. Is there any error?

Comment: I am new to Watir,I am working wih firefox...and its not selecting.I can not install chrome..there some restrctions...could you please try once on firefox....please let me know.

Comment: Yes as you say it's not working in Firefox, I tried all possible ways but it's not working. it's working in Chrome without any problem

Comment: Yes,Gopal,you are right...its working with Chrome...but,its not working with Mozilla,i found ,watir is supported till MOzilla 40 only..not beyond that...

Comment: No it's supported until 47, but for 48, you need to include geckodriver.

Answer (score 0):

It works as expected with Firefox 45: https://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/firefox/releases/45.4.0esr/

Please downgrade to that version and try again; I just ran through your script without error. (after adding `ie.link(:text,'Create account').click`, of course).